# In ExtJS, how do I load a store when I display a grid?

Tags: javascript, extjs

In ExtJS, how do I load a store when I display a grid? I want the store to load only when the grid is displayed (the user clicks on a button to show the grid, so it's wasteful to load the store beforehand). I tried the `afterrender` listener but it renders the loadmask in the wrong location, and the `afterlayout` listener reloads the grid every time the grid is resized.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is one of those things that can be a bit of a pain to accomplish because were giving the browser too much to do at once (particularly noticeable in IE).

I like to use a combination of defer to let the browser recover long enough to render things properly.

```
var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    ...,
    listeners : {
       render : function(grid){      
           grid.body.mask('Loading...');
           var store = grid.getStore();
           store.load.defer(100, store);
       },
       delay: 200
    }
});
```

Playing with the value of delay/defer should give you the desired results. The length of time you will need to delay/defer is dependent upon how complex your Grid is and how fast the browser is.

Also remember to remove the mask when your Store's load has completed.

```
listeners: {
    load: function(){
        yourGrid.body.unmask();
    }
}
```

NOTE: Just a few clarifications to the answer by Lloyd - you do not need to set autoLoad to false, because that is the default (ie: don't set it at all) and it sounds like from your description that you would want to use the Stores load method, instead of reload.

Comment: This is a good approach, though I would only apply masking if you find you actually need it.  If it loads too quickly then the mask might look like a flicker.  Also, make sure you unmask in the store's load event handler.  The layout browser combination example "Tabs with Nested Layouts" uses this on render method of store loading in its inner grid: http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/layout-browser/layout-browser.html

Comment: I agree with Brian's comments - forget about doing this if your data comes back in less than ~5 seconds. The user will never notice it.

Added a tidbit about removing the mask, thanks.

Comment: Nice one.. Just wonder, what is the use of 'delay: 200'? Is that necessary?

Comment: shouldn't listening on the 'show' event instead of 'render' bring the same effect ?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered handling `activate` event? You can add an event handler that loads data on `activate` event and then removes itself.

```
this.on('activate', function(){
 this.un('activate', arguments.callee);
    this.store.load();
}, this);
```

Here `this` refers to `GridPanel`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set autoLoad to false for the store and just call store.reload(); when the user clicks on the button to show the grid.

Comment: This works, but then it means that the grid is not responsible for its own store. It's fine if you're sharing a store across multiple components, but for a single grid, I'd rather have the grid be responsible for store loading.